# Set Label text nested inside of a Gridview based on JSON data using AJAX

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have a grid view that gets data from a vb.net class object. Inside this gridview is a TempleteField that (currently) has a label control, as so....

```html
<asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="grid3" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Column1" HeaderText="Account Number" />                    
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Column2" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Column3" HeaderText="Status" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Discount Program">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hiddenField1" />
                <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" class="message" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I need to have the test of the lblMessage changed based on data from a JSON object called through AJAX. JSON Data is a separate datasource from the class object used to populate the gridview. It looks like this:

```
{
    "00":
    {
        "Account": "1111",
        "Status": "Y",
        "Message": "Some Message Goes Here"
    },
    "01":
    {
        "Account": "1111",
        "Status": "N",
        "Message": ""
    }
}
```

I can't edit the class that the gridview is bound to for many reasons, so I need to use jQuery to change the label text in the gridview to the "Message" value called from the JSON object on load where the Key in the JSON object ("00", "01") matches the value of the hidden field that is nested along side the label. The hidden field value is set in the code-behind along with the rest of the gridview on the RowDataBound event. Here' the jQuery/Ajax so far..

```js
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var accountNumber = "123456";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "Http://MyURL",
                data: accountNumber,
                success: function (data) {
                    //Some Code Here
                }
            });
        };
    </script>
```

I'm at a bit of a loss from here. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We worked it out

We first set the CssClass of the label object, instead of the value of the hidden field, to match the key value of the JSON object in the code behind on the RowDataBound event. Then set the label.text value by finding the span and class via JQuery:

```js
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 contentType: "application/json",
 url: "http://MyURL",
 data: accountNumber,
 success: function (data) {  
  if (data) {
   var parseData = JSON.parse(data)
   var table = $('.grid3');
   if (table !== null && table !== undefined) {
    $.each(parseData, function (key, val) {
                                var labelObject = table.find('span[class="' + key + "]');
     var message = val.Message;               
     if (labelObject !== null && labelObject !== undefined) {
      labelObject.html(message);
     }
    });
   }
  }
 },
```

And success!